# How to append types in tuple type in typescript

Tags: typescript, types

I would like to applend types in following tuple. by using spread syntax, I would like to achieve this.

```
type A = [a:number,b:string] 
type B = [...A,c:boolean]
```

my desired result is like `type B = [a:number,b:string,c:boolean]`

But it returned following error.

`Tuple members must all have names or all not have names.ts(5084)`

[image]

What is the root cause of this?  if someone has opinion, will you please let me know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [microsoft/TypeScript#43516](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/43516) for an authoritative answer to this question.

You are using [labeled tuple elements](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-0.html#labeled-tuple-elements); the `a`, `b`, and `c` in your tuples are *labels* that may help with documentation but don't affect assignability.

According to the TypeScript release notes, one of the rules of labeled tuple elements is either *all* elements of a tuple should be labeled, or *none* of them should be labeled.  In the type

```
type B = [...A, c: boolean];
```

the initial [variadic tuple](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-0.html#variadic-tuple-types) spread of type `A` is not labeled, but the last element of type `boolean` is labeled, so it's an illegal type.

According to microsoft/TypeScript#43516, you need to give a name to that initial rest element:

```
type B = [...args: A, c: boolean]; 
// --------> ^^^^^^ <----- give this a label
// type B = [a: number, b: string, c: boolean]
```

Of course this is a bit weird because the labels from `A` overrode the `args` label from `B`, so you're basically forced to provide something that is immediately ignored.

But according to [microsoft/TypeScript#39941](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/39941) (see [this comment](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/39941#issuecomment-778868736)) and the discussion in [microsoft/TypeScript#43744](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/43744), the rule is in place because there *are* cases where the label is necessary and it's apparently hard to tell the difference syntactically.

For example, if `A` were a regular array type, then you get an output [tuple with a leading rest element](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-2.html#leadingmiddle-rest-elements-in-tuple-types), and that rest element would get the provided label:

```
type AA = number[];
type BB = [...args: AA, c: boolean];
// type BB = [...args: number[], c: boolean]
```

There are some comments in the issues linked about possibly relaxing the rule to allow cases like your code.  But so far it's not part of the language.

So there you go.  If you want to give one element in a tuple a label, you must do so for all elements, even on elements spread from other tuple types.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAglC8UDaBDAXFAdgVwLYCMIAnAGinwwGdgiBLTAcwF0BuAKFEigCEFkA6QSiINKGGGQDGGfAHtZAGwgpMrNgHp1UTtF6JUGHAWJkKUanUZSZ8pSqZsO4aDDiIjhIkjU6eegUIiYrASUNLktsqq7Jrazn58SIL8wqKGeJ7e1hGKUUxAA)

Answer (score 0):

Apparently you have to write it like

```
type A = [a: number, b: string]
type B = [...unused_but_required_label: A, c: boolean]
```

I have no idea why. Editor suggested an autofix when I tried

```
type B = [label: ...A, c: boolean] // error: label should be before rest dots
```

Answer (score 0):

create a new type as an array, spreading the above tuple types in the new type in the array.

You can just do this:

```
type A = [a:number,b:string] 
type B = [c:boolean]

type C = [...A, ...B]
```

[Typescript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=4&ssc=22&pln=1&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAglC8UDaBDAXAOwK4FsBGEATgDR5oDOwhAlhgOYC6UAsAFCiRQBCCyAxmjwB7IQBsIKDAzZsO0AMK8kAOlUxiUVcq4MgA)